# SwiftUI ScrollView BlendMode Issues

Tags: ios, swiftui

I have run into an issue with SwiftUI and ScrollView. When I have a subview with a blend mode attribute in a scrollview, the blend does not affect what is behind the scrollview. But if I put the same item in a Stack, it does affect the background.

I tried to apply the blend mode directly to the scrollview, but since there are other items in the subview that are not blended, it messes that up.
Here is a sample to illustrate the issue. with this, you can see the gradient blend works in the Stack but not in the scrollview.

```
let mode: BlendMode = .overlay

func item(_ num: Int) -> some View {
    return AnyView(
        ZStack {
            Rectangle()
                .fill( LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [Color.blue, Color.black]), startPoint: .top, endPoint: .bottom))
                .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                .blendMode(mode)
        
            Text("Number = \(num)")
                .font(.headline)
                .foregroundColor(Color.white)
        }
    )
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Rectangle()
                .fill(RadialGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [Color.black, Color.red]), center: .topLeading, startRadius: 200, endRadius: 800))
            
            HStack (spacing: 50) {
                VStack (spacing: 50) {
                    ForEach((1...5).reversed(), id: \.self) {
                        item($0)
                    }
                }
                
                ScrollView {
                    VStack (spacing: 50) {
                        ForEach((1...5).reversed(), id: \.self) {
                            item($0)
                        }
                    }
                }
                //.blendMode(mode)

                /*
                 blendMode for item() in ScrollView does not work.
                                                
                 Uncomment blendMode modifier above to get gradient blend, but text is not correct
                 */
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have also tried to apply the black-to-red Rectangle as a background of the Scrollview, and that doesn't fix it, either.

```
ScrollView {
    VStack (spacing: 50) {
        ForEach((1...5).reversed(), id: \.self) {
            item($0)
            
        }
    }
    
}
.background(
    Rectangle()
        .fill(RadialGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [Color.black, Color.red]), center: .topLeading, startRadius: 200, endRadius: 800))
)
```

In the pictures below, the look I want is in the left VStack.

[No blend mode modifier on ScrollView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wm2j0.png)

[Blend mode modifier applied to Scrollview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QfDzC.png)

Any idea how to get around this?

Only thing I could think, which seems very hacky, was to basically create two scrollviews z-stacked with blend applied to only the scrollview needing it and then put the items not blended in the topmost scrollview.

However, I don't think that is viable as I see no way to sync scrolling across the two scrollviews.

Answer (score 0):

I've come across a similar issue and from experimenting it seems as though the blend modes are affected when the SwiftUI `View` with the blend mode set is directly inside a `UIHostingView` (such as a `ScrollView`).

You can get the correct blending by placing another SwiftUI view below the one with the blend mode inside the scroll view, e.g.

```swift
ScrollView {
    ZStack {
        Rectangle()
          .fill(RadialGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [Color.black, Color.red]), center: .topLeading, startRadius: 200, endRadius: 800))
    
        VStack (spacing: 50) {
            ForEach((1...5).reversed(), id: \.self) {
                item($0)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This doesn't quite fix the issue in your example as the two backgrounds are not quite aligned, but in a case where the scroll view takes up the screen it might help.

It seems that adding a `.background` to the scroll view adds it below the `ScrollView` rather than at the bottom of the hierarchy in the `ScrollView` which is why that doesn't seem to fix it.

My issue was in a `List` row (which is backed by a `UITableView`), and setting an explicit background on the item inside the `List` helped there. Hopefully this will point you/others in the right direction.